# Invalid depfile: C:\xxx\xxx\Flutter\project_name\.dart_tool\flutter_build\df4b308df1ee4bce22c56c71751554d1\kernel_snapshot.d Invalid

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error in flutter I am aware that it is due to old packages. I cleaned the old packages in the pubspecyaml file but my problem is not solved.

Invalid depfile: C:\xxx\xxx\Flutter\project_name.dart_tool\flutter_build\df4b308df1ee4bce22c56c71751554d1\xxx.d
Invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the ide terminal and run the codes in order:

```
flutter clean
```

> 

```
flutter pub get
```

I hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had currently this error and helped me removing that {app}.dart_tool\flutter_build\df4b308df1ee4bce22c56c71751554d1 folder.